# Why is this change of order in integration correct?

Tags: integration, analysis

I have a double integral of the form for a given $x$

$$\int_0^x \int_w^\infty f(u) du dw $$

with a nice "properly behaved" $f$, i.e. all integral exists. Why is the above equivalent to

$$\int_0^\infty \min{(x,w)} f(w) dw $$

The note says change of order of integral implies this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to see this is to introduce a new function $\delta$ with $\delta(u,w) = 1$ for $u \geq w$ and $0$ otherwise. Now we get

$$\int_0^x \int_w^\infty f(u) du dw = \int_0^x \int_0^\infty \delta(u,w) f(u) du dw = \int_0^\infty f(u) \int_0^x \delta(u,w) dw du.$$

Note that $$\int_0^x \delta(u,w) dw = \min(x,u),$$
which readily proves your claim. One should note that this only works if you know for sure that you are allowed to interchange the integrals (for example in the case of absolute convergence, by Fubini's Theorem).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can think of this as $\int_0^s F(w)\;dw$, where $F(w) = \int_w^{\infty}f(t)\;dt$.

Now apply integration by parts, considering the original integral as $\int u\;dv$ with $u(t)=F(t)$ and $v(t) = t$.

Answer (score 1):

Since we always have $w < x$, we can divide the integral as
$$
\int_0^x\!\!\!\!\int_w^x f(u)dudw + \int_0^x \!\!\!\!\int_x^\infty f(u)dudw.
$$
The regions of integration for these integrals are simple shapes, so the order can be easily interchanged to give
\begin{multline}
\int_0^x\!\!\!\!\int_0^uf(u)dwdu + \int_x^\infty\!\!\!\! \int_0^xf(u)dwdu \\= \int_0^xuf(u)du + \int_x^\infty xf(u)du = \int_0^\infty \min(x,u)f(u)du
\end{multline}